Calculate hours within and outside business hours on TimeSheet
I need to calculate hours within and outside business hours on the TimeSheet object from the related TimeSheetEntry records.
My code was working, but not calculating correctly. I'm trying to update my helper class to calculate the correct values, but am struggling with an error on BusinessHours.
Can someone help me adjust this so it works correctly?
Here is my helper class:
public class TimesheetHelper {
    public static void calculateTimesheetHours(Set<Id> timesheetIds) {
        if (timesheetIds.isEmpty()) return;

        // Get the default Business Hours Id
        BusinessHours businessHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true LIMIT 1];
        Id businessHoursId = businessHours.Id;

        // Query related TimesheetEntry records
        Map<Id, List<TimesheetEntry>> timesheetEntriesMap = new Map<Id, List<TimesheetEntry>>();
        for (TimesheetEntry entry : [
            SELECT Id, TimesheetId, StartTime, EndTime
            FROM TimesheetEntry 
            WHERE TimesheetId IN :timesheetIds
        ]) {
            if (!timesheetEntriesMap.containsKey(entry.TimesheetId)) {
                timesheetEntriesMap.put(entry.TimesheetId, new List<TimesheetEntry>());
            }
            timesheetEntriesMap.get(entry.TimesheetId).add(entry);
        }

        // Prepare timesheet updates
        List<TimeSheet> timesheetsToUpdate = new List<TimeSheet>();
        for (Id timesheetId : timesheetIds) {
            Decimal totalBusinessHours = 0.00;
            Decimal totalOutsideHours = 0.00;

            if (timesheetEntriesMap.containsKey(timesheetId)) {
                for (TimesheetEntry entry : timesheetEntriesMap.get(timesheetId)) {
                    if (entry.StartTime != null && entry.EndTime != null) {
                        DateTime entryStart = entry.StartTime;
                        DateTime entryEnd = entry.EndTime;

                        // Calculate business hours for the time entry using BusinessHours.diff()
                        Long businessMillisecondsStart = BusinessHours.diff(businessHoursId, entryStart, entryStart);
                        Long businessMillisecondsEnd = BusinessHours.diff(businessHoursId, entryEnd, entryEnd);

                        Decimal businessHoursCalculated = (businessMillisecondsStart != null ? businessMillisecondsStart : 0) + (businessMillisecondsEnd != null ? businessMillisecondsEnd : 0);
                        businessHoursCalculated = businessHoursCalculated / (1000 * 60 * 60); // Convert to hours

                        // Calculate total hours of the entry (outside business hours calculation)
                        Long totalMilliseconds = entryEnd.getTime() - entryStart.getTime();
                        Decimal totalHours = totalMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60);

                        // Calculate hours outside business hours
                        Decimal outsideBusinessHours = totalHours - businessHoursCalculated;

                        // Accumulate totals
                        totalBusinessHours += businessHoursCalculated;
                        totalOutsideHours += outsideBusinessHours;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the Timesheet record
            TimeSheet timesheet = new TimeSheet(
                Id = timesheetId,
                Total_Hours_Within_Business_Hours__c = totalBusinessHours.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP),
                Total_Hours_Outside_Business_Hours__c = totalOutsideHours.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
            );
            timesheetsToUpdate.add(timesheet);
        }

        // Update timesheets
        if (!timesheetsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update timesheetsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}

This is the code that was working, but not calculating the correct results:
public class TimesheetHelper {
    public static void calculateTimesheetHours(Set<Id> timesheetIds) {
        if (timesheetIds.isEmpty()) return;

        // Get the default Business Hours Id
        Id businessHoursId = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true LIMIT 1].Id;

        // Query related TimesheetEntry records
        Map<Id, List<TimesheetEntry>> timesheetEntriesMap = new Map<Id, List<TimesheetEntry>>();
        for (TimesheetEntry entry : [
            SELECT Id, TimesheetId, StartTime, EndTime
            FROM TimesheetEntry
            WHERE TimesheetId IN :timesheetIds
        ]) {
            if (!timesheetEntriesMap.containsKey(entry.TimesheetId)) {
                timesheetEntriesMap.put(entry.TimesheetId, new List<TimesheetEntry>());
            }
            timesheetEntriesMap.get(entry.TimesheetId).add(entry);
        }

        // Prepare timesheet updates
        List<Timesheet> timesheetsToUpdate = new List<Timesheet>();
        for (Id timesheetId : timesheetIds) {
            Decimal totalBusinessHours = 0;
            Decimal totalOutsideHours = 0;

            if (timesheetEntriesMap.containsKey(timesheetId)) {
                for (TimesheetEntry entry : timesheetEntriesMap.get(timesheetId)) {
                    if (entry.StartTime != null && entry.EndTime != null) {
                        // Total hours between start and end time
                        Long totalMilliseconds = entry.EndTime.getTime() - entry.StartTime.getTime();
                        Decimal totalHours = totalMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60);

                        // Calculate time within business hours
                        Long businessMilliseconds = BusinessHours.diff(businessHoursId, entry.StartTime, entry.EndTime);
                        Decimal businessHours = (businessMilliseconds != null) ? businessMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60) : 0;

                        // Calculate time outside business hours
                        Decimal outsideBusinessHours = totalHours - businessHours;

                        // Accumulate totals
                        totalBusinessHours += businessHours;
                        totalOutsideHours += outsideBusinessHours;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the Timesheet record
            Timesheet timesheet = new Timesheet(
                Id = timesheetId,
                Total_Hours_Within_Business_Hours__c = totalBusinessHours,
                Total_Hours_Outside_Business_Hours__c = totalOutsideHours
            );
            timesheetsToUpdate.add(timesheet);
        }

        // Update timesheets
        if (!timesheetsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update timesheetsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}


I figured it out!

    public class TimeSheetHelper {
    public class HourCount {
        public Decimal nightHours = 0;
        public Decimal dayHours = 0;
    }

    public static HourCount calculateBusinessAndNonBusinessHours(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime) {
        HourCount hours = new HourCount();

        // Get the default Business Hours
        BusinessHours businessHours = [SELECT Id, IsDefault FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true LIMIT 1];
        Id businessHoursId = businessHours.Id;

        // Manually calculate the start and end of business hours (e.g., 8 AM and 5 PM)
        DateTime businessStart = DateTime.newInstance(startTime.date(), Time.newInstance(8, 0, 0, 0));  // 8 AM
        DateTime businessEnd = DateTime.newInstance(startTime.date(), Time.newInstance(17, 0, 0, 0));  // 5 PM

        Decimal morningMinutes = 0;
        Decimal eveningMinutes = 0;

        // If the start time is before business hours, treat it as outside business hours (evening)
        if (startTime < businessStart) {
            eveningMinutes += businessStart.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
            startTime = businessStart;
        }

        // If the end time is after business hours, treat it as outside business hours (evening)
        if (endTime > businessEnd) {
            eveningMinutes += endTime.getTime() - businessEnd.getTime();
            endTime = businessEnd;
        }

        // Calculate the duration inside business hours
        if (startTime < businessEnd && endTime > businessStart) {
            if (endTime > businessStart) {
                morningMinutes = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
            }
        }

        // Convert the total minutes to hours
        hours.nightHours = eveningMinutes / (1000 * 60 * 60); // Outside business hours
        hours.dayHours = morningMinutes / (1000 * 60 * 60); // Within business hours

        // Round to 2 decimal places
        hours.nightHours = hours.nightHours.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        hours.dayHours = hours.dayHours.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        return hours;
    }

    public static void calculateTimesheetHours(Set<Id> timesheetIds) {
        if (timesheetIds.isEmpty()) return;

        // Query related TimesheetEntry records
        Map<Id, List<TimesheetEntry>> timesheetEntriesMap = new Map<Id, List<TimesheetEntry>>();
        for (TimesheetEntry entry : [
            SELECT Id, TimesheetId, StartTime, EndTime
            FROM TimesheetEntry 
            WHERE TimesheetId IN :timesheetIds
        ]) {
            if (!timesheetEntriesMap.containsKey(entry.TimesheetId)) {
                timesheetEntriesMap.put(entry.TimesheetId, new List<TimesheetEntry>());
            }
            timesheetEntriesMap.get(entry.TimesheetId).add(entry);
        }

        // Prepare timesheet updates
        List<TimeSheet> timesheetsToUpdate = new List<TimeSheet>();
        for (Id timesheetId : timesheetIds) {
            Decimal totalBusinessHours = 0;
            Decimal totalOutsideHours = 0;

            if (timesheetEntriesMap.containsKey(timesheetId)) {
                for (TimesheetEntry entry : timesheetEntriesMap.get(timesheetId)) {
                    if (entry.StartTime != null && entry.EndTime != null) {
                        // Use the helper function to calculate hours
                        HourCount hourCounts = calculateBusinessAndNonBusinessHours(entry.StartTime, entry.EndTime);

                        // Accumulate totals
                        totalBusinessHours += hourCounts.dayHours;
                        totalOutsideHours += hourCounts.nightHours;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the Timesheet record
            TimeSheet timesheet = new TimeSheet(
                Id = timesheetId,
                Total_Hours_Within_Business_Hours__c = totalBusinessHours,
                Total_Hours_Outside_Business_Hours__c = totalOutsideHours
            );
            timesheetsToUpdate.add(timesheet);
        }

        // Update timesheets
        if (!timesheetsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update timesheetsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}

